# Is it good to include title="" within your links?

Tags: html, seo, accessibility

I am developing a website and for the main navigation, I was thinking it would be a good idea to include the title attribute.

```
<a href="/results/" title="Results">Results</a>
```

Is this a good thing to do? Also, is it good for SEO and accessibility?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is a great thing to do.  For accessibility, for SEO, for standards, for good netiquette.
You may want to make them slightly more descriptive though: title="Results of your Search" or "Results of Test #2"

Comment: It's also handy because most browsers will display it in the tooltip if you hover over the link.

Answer (score 7):

From [this article](http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol2/html_no1.htm):

> The TITLE attribute is useful in places where your HTML design limits the length of your link text.
>
> That's often the case for links in a navigation bar, especially if your page has a multi-column layout.
>
> Try using the TITLE attribute to give your visitors extra navigation information.

There was some concern about the [support of this feature](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/980111.html) in the early days (1998!), but it is now a great way to reinforce the so-called **[information scent](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20030630.html)**

Answer (score 3):

Check out [H33: Supplementing link text with the title attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20071211/H33.html).

It's good to do for the sake of a more semantically meaningful document and potentially adds SEO value, but different browsers have different levels of support for it.

- You can't search for title text in a document via the keyboard
- You can't control the appearance, location, or duration of the title element (without replacing titles with some Javascript bastardization)
- People using screen readers might find it awkward to hear both link text and a description of it (although at least with JAWS, you can change a setting to enable / disable this)

Comment: You mentioned JAWS, a free alternative to JAWS is firevox (http://firevox.clcworld.net/) which is an add-on to firefox, worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, very important for users of your site using assistive technologies like screenreaders.

Answer (score 1):

It also helps if you want to be a bit more verbose and you don't have much space for the real link text.

Answer (score 0):

Also, to add to the other answers, if you do any automated testing it's nice to have as many attributes as possible to be able to identify the various widgets.

Comment: Each element can have an ID to identify it. You don't need a title for this purpose.